# Parenting armature to mesh with automatic weights

Tags: rigging, armature, parent, inverse-kinematics

I'm just beginning in the animation world and I've been studying Blender – so far it's been good but now I've got a snag. Whenever I parent my mesh to a certain armature or bone on the right side of my mesh and flip it to the left I get a weird movement on the left hand side. It deforms in a very twisted way.

I'd really appreciate some help. I've attached a picture.

Thank you.

Comment: please share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your images didn't show up correctly. Generally when this happens to me I make sure modifiers are applied, the origin is centered to the mesh, and check my work using weight-painting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, first you parented your armature to your mesh objects, then you and then "flip"?

Firstly, flip what? How?
Secondly, whether it's your rig or your mesh, you should have finished editing them **before** parenting. Things will break if you edit after.

Either you know what you are doing enough so you know what damages it might cause and it won't be a huge trouble to fix the weights and relationships, or you don't have the experience to be able to predict such thing and you should just take the habit to always check you've done any possible edit before moving to the skinning process.